# What is the Typescript type for AbortController?

Tags: typescript, abortcontroller

I can't find any reference about how to define the type for `AbortController`. I am using it in a React component like so:

```
    const abortController = useRef();
    
    const doRequest = () => {
            abortController.current = new AbortController();
            window
                .fetch(url, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    signal: abortController.current.signal,
                })
                .then(res => res.json());
        };

const cancelRequest = () => {
  abortController.current.abort();
};
```

Comment: `AbortController` should be known https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b45cf0d694401aeec9023f731e5da7ad8e418f71/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L1900

Comment: Ordinarily yes, but I am getting `Object is possibly 'undefined'.` with reference to this line `abortController.current.abort();` for obvious reasons. So need to explicitly define the type that the variable `abortController` can hold.

Answer (score 1):

```
const abortController = useRef<AbortController>();
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

```
  type MutableRefObject<T> = {
    current: T | null;  // generic type 
};



  const abortController: MutableRefObject<AbortController> = useRef(null);
    
  const doRequest = () => {
          abortController.current = new AbortController();
          window
              .fetch(url, {
                  method: 'GET',
                  signal: abortController.current.signal,
              })
              .then(res => res.json());
      };

      

const cancelRequest = () => {
        abortController.current?.abort();  // ? for Optional chaining
};
```

Basically the type of `AbortController` is `AbortController` . I created the type
`MutableRefObject` for `useRef` hook . The `RefObject` provided by React  throws another error because the `current` property is readonly on `RefObject` .